# How to add a folder to a playlist in Banshee?

Tags: banshee

Now how do you add an entire folder to a playlist of Banshee. Say, you have a precious folder in which you have put your favorite songs one by one. How do you create a playlist for that folder?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using Banshee's “smart playlist“ feature:

1. Add a new smart playlist (Media → New Smart Playlist…)
2. Choose “File Location“ and “Starts With“ as a criterion
3. Enter the name of your folder. Note that it has to be a proper URL, i.e. something like `/home/user/Music/Favorites/`
4. Then add the folders by Media-Import Media

The advantage of such a “smart” playlist is that it dynamically adapts, so you can simply drop new files into that folder and they will appear in the playlist.

Comment: aint working. shows simply empty playlist. edit: it works, the file location must be `contains` not `is`

Answer (score 4):

To achieve what you want we will create a playlist then import it.

1. Open a terminal
2. Go to the directory your files are in : `cd /PathToMusicFiles`
3. `ls *.mp3 > playlist.m3u` (if you are not importing **.mp3** change the extension)
4. Open Banshee
5. **Media** -> **Import Playlist** (the file you want to import is **/PathToMusicFiles/playlist.m3u**)

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to get an answer to the same question. Tried danjjl's suggestion. But didn't work. (2nd step was my problem)  I used New Smart Playlist. It is working well. But it is not the best method.

Try this: Use New Smart Playlist and take this criterion (e.g.): File location, Contains, (Folder name) as content. Save it and try.

You will be able to add Folder with this suggestion. If it didn't work add more selection options by clicking the + sign to reach the desired folder. You can verify the number of files in the actual folder and the appeared number of files against the added folder name.

Comment: The link is dead for me... could you add the contents here instead?